# what can be form action in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controllers

when i click on submit button i want it to redirect to another jsp page with all details in text field ? but my whole code is in spring mvc ,
my code is

```
<form action="abc.jsp" method="post" target="idm-target">
                <input type="text" placeholder="User ID" name="userid" >
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" >
                <input type="text" placeholder="App Name" name="app-name" >

                <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Get Document" class="btn-submit" onclick="return submitForm();">
```

and i donot want to use controller for this ,,can anyone help me regarding this ?  Thanks

Comment: You can pass all this info to the Controller add all this info into params and redirect to another jsp with this info. But why you don't want to use Controllers?

Comment: can you just tell me what should i write in controllers for redirection

Comment: `return "redirect:/account";`